# pass a lambda with capture to a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, capture, std-function

I try to have a templated function to wrap any boolean expression or functor returning boolean.

```
template<typename BOOL_COND>
bool calculate(const BOOL_COND& bool_cond)
{
  return !(!(bool_cond));
}

assert( calculate( true ) );
assert( calculate( 1 == 1 ) );
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(11);
assert( calculate( ptr ) );
assert( calculate( []() { return 1 == 1;} ) );
assert( calculate( std::function<bool()>([]() { return std::string().empty();} )) );

std::function<bool(void)> f = [&]() -> bool { return ptr.get();};
assert( calculate( f ));
assert( calculate( std::function<bool(void)>([&]() -> bool { return ptr.get();} )) );

// assert( calculate( [&]() -> bool { return ptr.get();} ) ); // NOT WORK!!!


// clang-600.0.57 with -std=c++1y
```

I cannot pass a lambda with capture without explicit convert to std::function. what is the reason?  is there any solution without conversion?

a template specialization?? how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling the closure generated by the *lambda expression*, but merely using `bool_cond` as if it was a `bool` or was implicitly convertible to it.

You need to invoke `bool_cond` instead:

```
template<typename BOOL_COND>
bool calculate(const BOOL_COND& bool_cond)
{
  return !(!(bool_cond()));
}
```

The reason why `std::function` works is that it provides an [implicit conversion `operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool).

---

If you want an "uniform" `calculate` function that works both on *function objects* and things implicitly convertible `bool`, you will need two overloads constrained with `enable_if`:

```
template<typename BOOL_COND>
auto calculate(const BOOL_COND& bool_cond)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_invokable_v<const BOOL_COND&>>
{
    return !(!(bool_cond()));
}

template<typename BOOL_COND>
auto calculate(const BOOL_COND& bool_cond)
    -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_invokable_v<const BOOL_COND&>>
{
    return !(!(bool_cond));
}
```

With C++17:

```
template<typename BOOL_COND>
bool calculate(const BOOL_COND& bool_cond)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_invokable_v<const BOOL_COND&>)
    {
        return !(!(bool_cond()));
    }
    else
    {
        return !(!(bool_cond));
    }
}
```

---

Only slightly related, but I wrote an article that might interest you on various way to pass functions/lambdas to other functions: [**"passing functions to functions**"](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html).

Comment: Note that `std::is_invocable` is only present in C++17 as well, OP can check with a `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::declval<const BOOL_COND&>()(), std::declval<const BOOL_COND&>()()>::value>`